# How to request CVE if CNA didn't provide an answer

Tags: vulnerability, cve

A couple of weeks ago I have found a vulnerability in a product. I have contacted them reporting it a week ago and also to get the CVE.

I didn't receive any answer from the mailing list and I would like what can I do in such a situation. In Mitre's CVE documentation they said only CNA's can request the CVE.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CNAs can take more than a week to respond. Some are staffed by a small team - sometimes just one person - and if people are on holiday or off sick then there may be delays. If two weeks goes by  and you've got nothing back, that's more of a cause for concern.

If you feel like an excessive amount of time has passed you can opt to ask MITRE for a CVE directly and note in your application that the CNA did not respond. You should supply a timeline of communications to support this.